# Оптимальная сборка строки

Tags: java, строки

Как эффективней/целесообразней в Java собирать строку из частей? Через `String.format()`

```
String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s", table, cond)
```

или через `StringBuider`

```
builder.append("DELETE FROM ")
  .append(table)
  .append(" WHERE ")
  .append(cond).toString();
```

У `format` читабельность кода выше

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927630/java-string-concat-vs-stringbuilder-optimised-so-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.format отработает медленнее чем вариант со StringBuider.

Если у вас Java 8 или выше, то можете написать:

```
"DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + cond;
```

Компилятор такую простую конкатенацию внутри одного блока сам преобразует к вашему второму варианту со StringBuilder.

Comment: Можно ссылку где описывается такое поведение конкатенации?

Comment: И если вместо переменных будут функции, возвращающие `String` тоже будет равнозначно?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov тут, например, мелкими буквами https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1

Comment: в `StringBuilder` склеивание плюсами преобразуется очень давно (в 1.4 точно, правда еще в `StringBuffer`). В семерке добавили оптимизацию склейки строк на уровне С2 компилятора (т.е. не важно, как она клеится в исходном коде), но компилятор мог не распознать склейку из-за операций над склеиваемыми частями. В девятке склейку переделали на уровне javac, склейка плюсами одинаково хорошо работает как со значениями переменных и константами, так и с результатами выражений.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете сборку строки в цикле с последующим склеиванием с предыдущей, то однозначно StringBuilder, если просто сообщение, тогда String.format().